# Good architecture for desktop client application

Tags: oop, design-patterns, agile

I've already run several times into the issue of creating a desktop client app for working with some server, and every time I ended with ugly code, which becomes just impossible to support after couple of releases.

I have highlighted the following key points:

- All operations must be asynchronous, without any dummy windows for relative fast operations (i.e. less than 30 seconds)
- App has to periodically connect with the server and check, for example, user account
- All heavy operations must be cancelable

But, most important, all of this must be "naturally" in code, without creating unnecessary difficulties (singletons, hacks, etc)... only really needed code with minimal overhead.

How would you design such kind of app? What pattern would you use? What open source project with good architecture you can recommend?

Comment: Depending on the language you are using, it may exists a framework that has been designed with asynchronicity in mind. Did you already give a look at that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a little too broad, but instead of flagging I'll try and give an answer as I find the question interesting. I invite you to add more details if they come to mind.
Even though your design concerns the design of the application, there are a number of languages, patterns and technologies that would suit your requirements.
Keeping it general,

1. If your want your operations to be asynchronous, you are going to
   need multiple threads. Their implementation and use may vary
   depending on the language that you are using, but the concept behind
   is the same. So, just spawn a thread every time you need an
   asynchronous task, and implement a way to be noticed when the task is
   done (with or without errors). This can be done in a number of ways,
   since you asked for pattern I suggest you have a look at
   [observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).
2. The second requirement is not completely clear to me, I assume you
   want to periodically check that the client's data is aligned with the
   server's, and maybe perform security checks ("Are session and
   authentication credentials still valid?"). The first solution is to
   actually ask the server every *n* seconds, again using another
   thread. This kind of polling might not be the best option though: how
   do you factor in the possibility of connectivity issues? Even if your
   client cannot operate without a working connection to the server, it
   might bother the user to be disconnected and lose his work just
   because his Wi-Fi router rebooted. I would suggest you perform
   alignment checks at I/O, perhaps distinguishing between critical and
   non-critical ones. For example, if you decide the user's profile
   **has** to be aligned, then you would retrieve updated data from the server upon viewing it. On the other hand, if your app offers the
   user a list of cooking recipes and you don't care about him not
   viewing the one that has been inserted on the server 10 minutes in
   the past, you could simply cache these items and refresh them in a
   background thread every minute, without even noticing the user in
   case the update fails.   Last but not least, if you are also
   concerned with concurrent modifications of data, again based on your
   requirements you can decide to implement locks on data being edited,
   to performs checks on *save* operations to see if the data has
   changed in the meanwhile, or to simply let the user overwrite the
   data on the server no matter what.   All in all, hoping I interpreted
   your question correctly, this requirement is nontrivial and has to be
   adjusted to your particular use case.
3. Assuming the data is eventually saved on some sort of database on
   the server, one answer are [transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction), which allow you to
   treat even complex sequences of operations as "all or nothing",
   atomic instructions. You might implement your own system to have the
   same result, but I don't really see the point of not using this
   powerful instrument when possible.   Keep in mind one thing: I'm
   assuming "cancelable" means "cancelable before some point in time,
   and not after" (a sort of "undo"). If you're looking for complete
   revertability of any operation of data, the requirement becomes far
   more complex, and in general not possible to guarantee.

I believed I already answered in a way that helps you minimize "hacks" in code where possible. To recap:

1. You are going to need threads, and the observer pattern can help you
   keep the code clean.
2. Again, you can use threads, or focus on check on I/O operations. In
   the second case, you might consider an application layer
   specifically for client-server synchronization, embed it in one or
   more classes, and perform all your checks there. Have a look at the
   [proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).
3. Use transactions to revert operations, and issue a `COMMIT` only
   when you are sure that the operation is confirmed, a `ROLLBACK` in
   every other case. Encapsule this logic in your server's code so that
   the client is not aware of the actual transaction system being used,
   and your code should be quite clean.

Please comment if my answer is not satisfying or clear.

Comment: yeah, i'm really sorry for broad question! for me it is a little more concrete, but your answer is quite suits me. I was not sure, but you have confirmed some of my suggestions!